# Displaying flash message in portion of page that is otherwise not updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm looking to display my flash messages in a portion of the page that is otherwise not always in a partial that gets updated.

In other words, I may submit a form that updates a partial via ajax. But I want to display the flash message in a portion of the page that is outside of that partial.

I could have some javascript in every single necessary js.erb file to update the flash partial, but that seems crazy. Is there a more simple way of going about this?

I don't have to necessarily use flash messages either if something custom would work better.

Thanks!

Comment: partial what? I'm partial to pizza, but that probably doesn't apply here.

Comment: @MarcB In rails, a 'partial' is part of an html template that's been factored out into a separate file.

Comment: How are you doing the Ajax call and partial page update? Using a library or hand-rolled?

Comment: @Larry K: Usually from within a js.erb file using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the low-tech way by using a `:remote` call on your form that, when executed, will inject some HTML back into your page from a partial of your choosing.

It's pretty easy to do in a `.rjs` view:

```
page['flash'].html(render(:partial => 'flash'))
```

You can also do it in a `.js.erb` view using jQuery:

```
$('#flash').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'flash')) %>");
```

I tend to think the `.js.erb` method is a lot more ugly, but we all have our preferences.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to avoid having to have that in every .js.erb file, but that might be the only (or best) way.

Comment: That's why `.rjs` is a simpler approach. It's just a single line with no requirement for escaping. You don't need to have multiple views if they all do the same thing. Just `render(:action => 'common_rjs')` where `common_rjs` is the name of your common view.